# Container begin / end / cbegin / cend semantics, iterator / const_iterator compatibility

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++17, const-correctness

I've been working on a custom *ReversibleContainer*, and I thought I was on the right track, but I've hit a snag in testing while going through the semantics of the [*Container* named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) which makes me think I've fundamentally mis-implemented this. I'm working with C++17.

In particular, my current implementation is formed somewhat like this (pardon errors, I'm condensing it to an example as I type here), where:

- `Item` is the type the container holds
- `element` is the type iterators dereference to (it's convertible to `Item`)
- `struct` is used for overall brevity in this snippet
- only the types and members that I think are relevant are included

```
struct my_container {

    using value_type = Item;
    using reference = value_type &;
    using const_reference = const value_type &;
    using size_type = std::vector<Item>::size_type;
    using difference_type = std::vector<Item>::difference_type;

    struct element { 
        // ... 
    };

    // V is value type, D is part of forward/reverse iterator control
    template <typename V, int D> struct iterator_ {

        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = V;
        using reference = V &;
        using pointer = V *;
        using difference_type = my_container::difference_type;

        iterator_ (); // custom
        iterator_ (const iterator_<V,D> &) = default;
        iterator_ (iterator_<V,D> &&) = default;
        ~iterator_ () = default;

        iterator_<V,D> & operator = (const iterator_<V,D> &) = default;
        iterator_<V,D> & operator = (iterator_<V,D> &&) = default;

        bool operator == (const iterator_<V,D> &) const;

        // ...

    };

    using iterator = iterator_<element, 1>;
    using const_iterator = iterator_<const element, 1>;
    using reverse_iterator = iterator_<element, -1>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = iterator_<const element, -1>;

    iterator begin ();
    iterator end ();
    const_iterator cbegin () const;
    const_iterator cend () const;

    reverse_iterator rbegin ();
    reverse_iterator rend ();
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin () const;
    const_reverse_iterator crend () const;

};
```

Now, I'm looking at the operational semantics of `begin`, `end`, `cbegin` and `cend` (where `a` is a `my_container`, and `C` is its type):

| expression | return type | semantics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a.begin()` | (const_)iterator | iterator to the first element of `a` |
| `a.end()` | (const_)iterator | iterator to one past the last element of `a` |
| `a.cbegin()` | const_iterator | `const_cast<const C&>(a).begin()` |
| `a.cend()` | const_iterator | `const_cast<const C&>(a).end()` |

And the problem with my current implementation is that this expression, derived from the `cbegin` (and likewise `cend`), is invalid:

```
a.cbegin() == const_cast<const my_container&>(a).begin()
```

Because my `iterator` and `const_iterator` types are incompatible due to the `const` being wrapped up in the iterator type via the template parameters to `iterator_`, and also because my `begin()` is not `const`. And now I'm getting that sinking feeling that I have a fundamental flaw in my implementation.

The second problem with my current implementation is that the requirements list the return type of `begin` and `end` as "(const_)iterator", and I am only just noticing the "(const_)" now. However, my `begin` and `end` do not return a `const_iterator`.

My conclusion, then, is that my implementation does not meet the operational semantics requirements of *Container*, and is therefore invalid in its current form. And now I'm sad. :(

So, I'm confused about:

- General compatibility requirements of `iterator` and `const_iterator`.
- The cv-qualifiers on the declaration of `begin()` and `end()`.

And my questions are:

1. Am I correct in my conclusion that my container currently fails to meet the requirements of *Container* wrt. `begin`, `end`, `cbegin`, and `cend`?
2. Do the `iterator` and `const_iterator` types need to be equality comparable with each other?
3. Does `const_iterator` need to be copy constructible and assignable from an `iterator`?
4. Do `begin()` and `end()` have to be declared as `const`?
5. Did I make a mistake in wrapping up the `const` in `iterator_::value_type`?
6. What does "(const_)iterator" mean for the return type of `begin` and `end`?

I realize that looks like a lot of questions but they all sort of boil down to the single question of what the requirements for interoperability between `iterator` and `const_iterator` are. I hope this post makes sense.

Comment: Open to better titles, this one is a bit rough...

Comment: `iterator` should be convertible to `const_iterator`. They can be unrelated types, but then they have to provide suitable conversions explicitly - a converting constructor or a conversion operator.

Comment: Your `begin` and `end` do appear to return `const_iterator`, when called on `const` container. You do declare `const_iterator begin () const;`

Comment: Anyway, before you go too far down that road - I don't believe proxy iterators (iterators where `operator*` returns something other than a reference to the container's value type) satisfy iterator requirements. This is the main reason why `std::vector<bool>` is not a proper container. You say "`element` is the type iterators dereference to (it's convertible to `Item`)" - that sounds like proxy iterator to me.

Comment: Ah I'm so sorry guys I made a typo in my snippet in the absolute worst spot, the ones that returned `const_iterator` should be `cbegin` and `cend`. Corrected.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, it is a proxy iterator.

Comment: @JasonC As a copy of what you are working with, they probably should be `cbegin` and `cend`, but as a copy of what you *should* be working with, the typo was actually correct. ;) Free tip: Try comparing your implementation of Container requirements to a standard container to see if they differ. If you choose `std::vector`, that could mean comparing your member functions to [`vector::begin()`, `vector::cbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin). Focus on just the three declarations applicable to your chosen dialect (C++17).

Comment: @JaMiT That's a good (and obvious in retrospect) tip; thank you. Will probably clear up a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iterator begin ();
iterator end ();
const_iterator begin () const;
const_iterator end () const;
const_iterator cbegin () const;
const_iterator cend () const;
```

And yes, `const_iterator it = iterator;` should work (but not the other way around), as should `==` (I am not certain the first is mandated, but you should still do it).

Also consider writing SCARY iterators, where the iterator is not a subtype of the container.

```
template<class T>
struct foo {
   template<class U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<U>, std::remove_cv_t<T>>,bool> =true>
   friend bool operator==( foo const& lhs, foo<U> const& rhs );
};
```

This is an example of a `==` that works between types.

Comment: Thanks; adding the `const` definition of `begin` and `end` seems to make everything a lot more consistent on the container end. Now I just need to work on the iterator compatibility. I figure I can add a `const_iterator` conversion operator to `iterator` and then write global comparison operators that take `const_iterator`s. Re: `==` and others I found a footnote at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container that says "Given `iterator` i and j, in the expressions i == j, i != j, i < j, i <= j, i >= j, i > j, i - j, either or both may be replaced by an object of the container's ...

Comment: ...  const_iterator type ... with no change in semantics." -- Which leads me to believe that *all* the comparisons need to take both. Or at least, that's how I'm going to make it work, seems like a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: No, iterators may not be converted to from const iterators; that violates the spirit of const correctness @jason  The other way around!

Comment: Yeah; `iterator :: operator const_iterator () const;`, is what I meant. Good lord, man, I may be tired but I'm not insane ! Rereading my comment I can see there are some conflicting ways to parse what I wrote; sorry about that.